# How to check live streaming url response iphone

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app I am doing live streaming with the following code :

```
-(void)playurl:(id)sender
{
    self.mpPlayer=[[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alwatan.lsops.net/live/alwradio_ar_audio.sdp/playlist.m3u8"]] autorelease];

    [self.mpPlayer prepareToPlay];

    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.mpPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 768, 400);        
    }
    else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        self.mpPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 500);
    }    
    [self.mpPlayer play];
    self.mpPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    //self.mpPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    self.mpPlayer.shouldAutoplay = TRUE;


    self.mpPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  object:mpPlayer]; 
    [scrollView addSubview:self.mpPlayer.view];
    if(isVideoPlay)
    {
        isVideoPlay = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        isVideoPlay = TRUE;
    }
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSError *error = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
    if (error) {
    }
    else
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer]; 
    }
}
```

Everything is fine but my problem is that is url is not runing then application will be crashed so how can I check the live streaming url response so I can mange the condition and give alert for url not respond.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use the following notification

```
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
```

and check for

```
      if(moviePlayer.state == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped)
{
// Alert
}
else  if(moviePlayer.state == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
{
// Alert
}
else  if(moviePlayer.state == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused)
{
// Alert
}
else  if(moviePlayer.state == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted)
{
// Alert
}

else  if(moviePlayer.state == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward)
{
// Alert
}
else  if(moviePlayer.state == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward)
{
// Alert
}
```

Comment: yes but when intrupted error occur i am giving worg ulr then it will come also in else condition not come in MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted condition

Answer (score 0):

My experience with `MPMoviePlayerControler` has been that it's not very good with error handling. One possibility would be to request the URL first, then only load the .m3u8 file when your stream is running.

You could use `NSURLConnection` and friends to try and load the stream, and, if necessary, read the file looking for something specific that indicates the stream is running (perhaps the presence of a line containing `#EXTINF:`.